# jQuery AJAX POST response populating select box issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm attempting to run this AJAX script when the plant select drop down list is changed to 1 or 2 sending the value get_option being 1 or 2.  It will run the query to get a list of tools that go with that plant number.  The toolselect dropdown is not being populated.

#### My script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function fetch_select(val) {
        $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "fetch_data.php",
                data: {
                      get_option:val
                      },
                success: function (response) {
                        $("toolselect").append(response); 
                }
                });
        }
        $("#plantselect").on("change", this, function(e) {
                                fetch_select($(this).val())

        });
}
```

Everything appears to be sending fine and receiving a 200 response from the fetch_data.php page.

#### Heres my fetch_data page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'x', 'x', 'x');
       if (!$conn) {
                    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
                    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
                    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
                    exit;
        }

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;
$plant = $_POST['get_option'];
$sql="SELECT toolnum FROM tools WHERE plant='$plant'";
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            echo "<option value='".$d['toolnum']."'>".$d['toolnum']."</option>";
        }
        /* Free statement and connection resources. */
        $stmt->close();
}           

?>
```

#### Lastly here is my html:

```
    <select name="plantselect" id="plantselect">
        <option value="">Select a Plant</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>


Select Tool:
    <select id="toolselect">
    </select>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Answer (score 3):

This selector won't find anything:

```
$("toolselect")
```

Because there is no such element like this:

```
<toolselect>
```

If you want to select based on the `id` attribute, you need to use the `#` symbol:

```
$("#toolselect")
```

---

Additionally, you should remove these and other debugging `echo` statements:

```
echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;
```

Statements like that can be useful for debugging, but not for production code.  At the very least, it would mean that you're trying to insert that raw text into a `select` element, which could just be silently failing since that wouldn't make sense for the element.

Comment: I did change it to #toolselect but same issue is happening.  I caught that when I was typing up my question.

Comment: @Greek Can you post the response you are getting from ajax call

Comment: @Greek: Specifically where/how is this failing then?  When you debug this, what does `response` contain in the AJAX success callback?  Those random `echo` statements may be causing a problem.

Comment: I'm actually getting the results in the response they're just not populating the main page's select box:  <option value=''></option><option value='10028-83'>.....

Comment: @Greek: You're getting the results, but you're also getting random debugging text.  Remove that output from the server-side code.  That text wouldn't belong in a `select` element and it could just be silently failing as a result.

Comment: Removed debugging info and receiving just the option values back.  Select box isn't populating.

Comment: @Greek: Does the jQuery selector find the element you expect it to find?  What is the exact value of `response`?  You need to do at least some debugging here.

Comment: @David sorry I'm kind of a noob with coding, but how can I tell if the selector is finding the element?  The response is actually pulling the correct column from my mysql database.  I can't list the whole thing because its too long.

Comment: @Greek: This is a good chance to take a look at the debugging tools in your web browser then.  You can place a breakpoint on the line with the selector to halt execution on that line.  Then use the console to execute that exact code (`$("#toolselect")`) and see what it returns.  You can also use that to examine the runtime values of variables, step through the code line by line to observe its runtime behavior, etc.

Comment: @David I think it's selecting it correctly  jQuery = function( selector, context ) {selector = "#toolselect", context = undefined}

Comment: @Greek: You *think* it is, or you have *confirmed* it is?  The point of debugging is to validate your assumptions.

Comment: @David thats what the selector: value is indicating so I would say confirmed.

Comment: @Greek: What value?  What is the actual result of executing that jQuery selector?  And what is the actual value of `response`?  You claim everything is correct and working, but given that something *isn't* working I'm going to have to assume you're missing something.

Comment: @David When I break at the $("#toolselect") and step into the function the local scope selector value shows "#toolselect".  The response is option values of the 203 tools values unless you want the response header: <option value=''></option><option value='10028-83'>.....

Comment: @David I think I realize my problem.  The toolselect class is part of a div that's being cloned on the page.  I think that the data is being filled into the initial toolselect div that being hidden so its not targeting the visible toolselect class.  Is there another way to change the selector to target whatever class the buttons click in?

Comment: @Greek: `toolselect` isn't a `class`, it's an `id`.  There should be only one instance of it on the page.  If there's more than one, the markup is invalid and the behavior of the JavaScript is undefined.